# Vs code break point does not not stop at Python-Django API TestCase

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging

Normally, debugging is just working fine with Container. I am spinning up my container at port 8000 and attaching the debugging port which is 3000 to it. But, when I hit my rest_api, although it stops from Swagger when it comes to being hit by TestCase debugger does not stop. I could not figure out the reason.

Comment: pdb doesn't work with test cases. install `ipdb` and try using it in your test cases. `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`